# Example of Cycle Notation and Elementary Transpositions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, symmetric-groups

How does one achieve the yellow box from the the second line of this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $s_1s_2s_1=(13)$.

Thus we have
$$(56)(45)(34)(13)=(65)(54)(43)(31)=(65431)=(16543)$$

Comment: thank you! what was the intention of reversing most of the 2-cycles in your second part? and why would this be legitimate?

Comment: @Brofessor Cyclic permutation has no effect on a cycle. For a 2-cycle, cyclic permutation just means reversing the numbers. $(13)$ and $(31)$ are identical; they exchange 1 and 3. It's completely symmetric.

Comment: @Brofessor As to the reason, at least for me it makes the final product more apparent. You can just read it from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually it is probably simplest to start by computing the two-line representation (last part of the equality you display), by tracing each element from right to left through the product of transposition.

Once you have that, tracing the cycle structure of the permutation should be routine.